# Disable asp button autopostback

Tags: c#

I have some buttons in my aspx page and in each button click a panel gets opened. Now, when I click the first button as it is on the top of the page the page remains same. But when I click the third or other button the panel gets opened but the page is again moved back to the top. I have to stop this page moment when ever I click the buttons.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Set the button `onclientclick="return false;"` will prevent postbacks.

Comment: Yes, this avoids postbacks. If you want to keep other parts of the page you can use partial postbacks (i.e. using an Update Panel) or use AJAX to implement required behaviour.

Comment: After using update panel also, while clicking on the button the page is getting reloaded

Comment: no out of the panel on this button click my panel have to open